# AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom not supporting DescendOrigin

Tags: xcm

I've noticed that `ShouldExecute` implementation for `AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom`([here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/xcm-builder/src/barriers.rs#L56)) doesn't allow execution of XCM if it starts with `DescendOrigin` instruction. This will always be the case when `xcm->send(...)` is used by non-sovereign account. I haven't executed **xcm->send** without *sudo* until recently so this little bit has eluded me so far.

I'd like to understand if this is intentional or not - is there a known security risk of allowing such execution type?

I cannot think of any issue since user can only manipulate origin either by clearing it or descending it further.

Comment: Good question! I also encountered this requirement and added a custom barrier to solve it. I would also like to know if there is a security risk

Answer (score 1):

I didn't come out with a security reason yet. Maybe I don't have too much knowledge of this.

It's a downgrade privilege operation.

---

IMHO, the XCMP is not fully ready yet. It's still HRMP.

If we allow anyone to use that, it might cause some network/storage issues.

Just a personal idea.

Comment: I agree with the part about security - to my knowledge, I cannot see any problems.

Regarding HRMP, I don't think it should make a difference since that's just a protocol for transferring XCM - not executing it.